# Should I delete duplicate questions?

Tags: support, duplicate-questions, deleted-questions

I have some questions which are marked as duplicate.

Should I delete them?

It is sometimes downvoted.

Comment: You mean the questions asked by you?

Comment: Yes. I have already deleted some.

Comment: See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5221/how-does-deleting-work-what-can-cause-a-post-to-be-deleted-and-what-does-that

Comment: Somehow ironic that this is a duplicate, but was at the top of my Google search.

Comment: @RobertLongson I think OP is saying that they find out their question is a duplicate _after_ posting, i.e. they're not intentionally asking questions that have already been asked.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

It depends. As always.

Consider these scenarios:

- **Your question isn't answered by the duplicate**

  Edit your question to explain how your context is different from the duplicate, adding enough details so users will understand what sets your question apart. If your question is closed by a single gold-badge holder, [@-reply](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) that user in the comment section so that the question can be reopened.
- **You searched for *foo*, the duplicate doesn't mention *foo* but still answers your question**

  Keep your question as a signpost for future visitors who search for *foo* as well.
- **Your search skills were lacking when you asked and future visitors will find the duplicate also without your question**

  Delete your question. It is noise and makes it harder for future visitors to find what they are looking for.
- **You didn't search or experiment at all; you simply went from error ➜ post a question in less than an hour**

  Your question shouldn't be on the site in the first place; delete it.

Comment: @JonasWilms only dupe hammers are pingable on a gold badge hammered question. Your edit only applies to those cases.

Comment: Hmm ... But just editing the question doesn't help right? I always thought the original dupevoter could also be pinged

Comment: @JonasWilms overall [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/43019/how-do-comment-replies-work/43020#43020) doesn't say so. On closing, the orignal dupe comment gets deleted and that removes the orginal dupe voter from pingable canidates

Comment: @JonasWilms after some consultation in two chat rooms I made an edit to explain when a dupe voter can be pinged. I'm happy to hear if further improvements are needed.